# Alginate nanoparticles

Tags: polymers

I want to produce alginate nanoparticles from NaAlg. I choosed nebulizing NaAlg solution into $\ce{CaCl2}$ solution but 2% (m/v) NaAlg solution is quite viscous. What should I do to make it inviscid?

Answer (score 2):

Dilute the feed solution tenfold, etc.  Inelegant.  Try solution engineering,

http://www1.lsbu.ac.uk/water/kosmos.html 
Chaotropes and kosmotropes.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_solvent 
Add a little "poor" solvent like ethanol or acetone to ball the polymer, disrupting hydrogen bond crosslinking and reducing chain entanglement.

You want a novel solution not obvious to one skilled in the art.  That qualifies it for patent protection.  A large fraction of the hard answers you need already exist.  They were done by other people doing other things.  Accumulate bone piles of knowledge.  The process for creating ceramic dislocation-pinned nickel superalloys works for Plexiglass, which "dissolves" 30 wt-% copper phthalocyanine as a dye masterbatch.  So it can't be done, so what?  Do it the "other" way.

Answer (score 1):

Heating most viscous solution will decrease their viscosity. Most agar gels will liquefy when heated. Also, some polysaccharide solutions don't become viscous again when they cool down. I think alginate will become viscous, but you will have to test that out.